# M.L.E of Pareto distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I must find the M.L.E for the Pareto distribution

$$f(x|x_0)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha x_0^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}} & \text{ if } x\geq x_0, \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x<x_0.
\end{cases}$$

I end up with a likelihood function

$$\alpha^n x_0^{n\alpha}\prod\limits^n_{i=1}{1\over x_i^{\alpha+1}}.$$

Using the natural logarithm, my answer goes goes exactly like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399209/how-to-find-the-maximum-likelihood-estimators-of-parameters-in-the-pareto-distri).

However, my solution sheet for the excercise states that I can't use the logarithm on the likelihood function in this case because it is undefined. Instead, I must define $T=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ so the likelihood function ends up looking like this

$$\frac{\alpha^n T^{n\alpha}}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha+1}}1_{\{T\geq x_0\}},$$

Where $1$ is the indicator function.

I have no idea what's going on. Every single solution I find for this excercise solves it as I did. Am I misinterpreting the problem or is the solution sheet is wrong? If so, why?

Comment: The point is you forgot to restrict your domain before you write your product (i.e., you forgot the case $x_0$ bigger than some $x_i$).  Log-likelihood is not defined when the likelihood is 0.

Comment: @user10354138 If the likelihood is $0$ then you might say the log-likelihood is $-\infty$ and so presumably not the maximum

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174150/find-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-pareto-distribution-and-a-unbiased-est